# Fixed selection area and stop new selection in jcrop

Tags: jquery, jcrop

i'm new in jQuery. and I'm trying to crop a picture using the jcrop plugin.
Here is my current code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    var width = '<%=Session["imageWidth"]%>';
    var height = '<%=Session["imageHeight"]%>';

    jQuery('#imgCrop').Jcrop({
        boxWidth: 800, 
        boxHeight: 600,
        onSelect: storeCoords,
        bgColor: 'pink',
        bgOpacity: .6,
        setSelect: [0, 0, width, height],
        aspectRatio: 1
    });

});

function storeCoords(c) {
    jQuery('#X').val(c.x);
    jQuery('#Y').val(c.y);
    jQuery('#W').val(c.w);
    jQuery('#H').val(c.h);
};
```

Here everything is ok but the selection area is resizable.
What should I change in order to fix the selection area and stop the new selection?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/346045/jquery-jcrop-how-to-set-a-fixed-size-selection-area

Comment: It's really easy, see this answer I just posted...

http://stackoverflow.com/a/16688696/2152144

Answer (score 3):

Use this code

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#imgCrop').Jcrop({
        aspectRatio: 1,
        setSelect:   [50, 0, 300,300],
        allowResize: false,
        allowSelect: false,
        onSelect: storeCoords
        });
    });

    function storeCoords(c) {
        jQuery('#X').val(c.x);
        jQuery('#Y').val(c.y);
        jQuery('#W').val(c.w);
        jQuery('#H').val(c.h);
    };
```