# jCrop, restrict croppable area

Tags: jquery, jcrop

Is there any option to restrict the croppable area of the image with jCrop.

I want to leave out a 10px area around the image for border purpose, so when user selects the crop region he should not be able to move beside the allowed croppable region.

[image]

For example, Image here is 400x300 px, and I want to restrict the croppable region to 380x280 px.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQuery JCrop - How to set a fixed size selection area?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/346045/jquery-jcrop-how-to-set-a-fixed-size-selection-area)

Comment: Did you solve this issue? If so please do add a comment.

Comment: No, I wasn't able to solve it

Answer (score 0):

Recently I faced a similar problem. Trying to solve it, I explored the source code of the Jcrop plugin and found the undocumented option, which makes exactly what is needed.

So in case if you need to restrict the croppable area with 10px from each side, it should look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('image').Jcrop({
        edge: {w: 10, n: 10, e: -10, s: -10},
        // all another options
    });
});
```

Note, that this option is available only in `2.0.x` version of the plugin.

Comment: That's great! I'll maybe check this out sometime.