# Setting a minimum height and width on JCrop

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, crop, jcrop

I am working on a set of email templates which lets users add text, images, change font and colours, etc. Now if the user wants to add an image in a specific area of the template, they will first click on that area where they want the image to be added and then add an image from the library in my application. Now let's consider that the acceptable dimensions of the area they clicked on the template is 500 * 500, and the image selected from the library is 1000 * 1000, in such a case the application will automatically bring up a cropping tool using which they can resize the image. However, I want to restrict the cropping tool to only be draggable to the minimum height OR width of the desired location in the template, i.e., in this example, they should not be able to drag the cropping tool any further below the height OR width of 500, although they can keep one or both dimensions above 500 as the cropping tool automatically resizes it back to 500 * 500 (for e.g. 800 * 500, or even 500 * 1000 is acceptable too as the cropping tool automatically resizes the image to fit in the template). I had a look at the [documentation](http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop_Manual.html) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/346045/jquery-jcrop-how-to-set-a-fixed-size-selection-area) but couldn't really find a suitable answer to my question. Here's some of my code which validates if an image needs to be cropped:

```
var SelectedAreaHeight; //returns the height of the area they clicked on the template
var SelectedAreaWidth; //returns the width similarly

function ImageClick(data)
{
var ReturnImageHeight; //returns the height of the area they clicked on
var ReturnImageWidth; //returns the width similarly

    $(".ResizeImage").each(function()
    {
        ReturnImageHeight = $(this).data("height");
        ReturnImageWidth = $(this).data("width");
    }
    });

    if (ReturnImageHeight > SelectedAreaHeight || ReturnImageWidth > SelectedAreaWidth)
    {
        //this checks if the selected image's height OR width is greater
        //than the  desired area in the template to bring up the cropping tool.
    }
}
```

Now is there a way I could just restrict the cropping tool in a way that it is not 'crop-able' below `SelectedAreaHeight` OR `SelectedAreaWidth` ? Also please ignore any problems with the sample code above as I haven't pasted all of my code (it does a lot more than just this).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ekhm :D
There is such an option in jcrop :)

http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop_Manual.html#Setting_Options

> minSize   :  array [ w, h ] : Minimum width/height, use 0 for unbounded
>   dimension n/a

Comment: I was going to post this away as an answer when I came across it but I couldn't answer my own question for the next 8 hours. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Ok :) Too bad you've lost some of your time. :D Next time use google or ctrl+f on manual :D 
I've founded solution with google. :) I've used jcrop but never needed such an option. 
<3 jcrop - cool plugin.